# React Router isn't working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I upgraded from `react Router v2` to `v4` and then everything was broken! I searched on google with errors and learned a thing that is latest version of react router is totally re-written. I tried to follow the docs for updating my app. However I copied codes from official docs and it is working perfectly But when I'm working with my components and structure it's not routing. I couldn't figure out the actual problem. everything seems OK but still it's not routing.

**Update**

I did figure out the problem. it was with rendering the component from `Route`. I was using `Component` in my code but it should be `component` that's why my code wasn't working. It didn't event throw an error !

**This code below is working for routing**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

const About = () => (
  <div>About page</div>
)
const Home = () => (
 <div>Home component</div> 
)
const AppComponent = () => (
 <div>App component is rendered as well</div> 
)

render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>   
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

**This code below isn't working for routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

const SignUp = () => (
  <div>This is Sign up Page</div>
)
const Home = () => (
 <div>Home component</div> 
)
const AppComponent = () => (
 <div>App component is rendered as well</div> 
)

render(
  <Router>
    <div className="container">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Red Dice</Link>
            </div>

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

    <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/" Component={AppComponent} />
    <Route  path="/signup" Component={SignUp} />
  </div>

</Router>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

I have another question about `browserHistory`. In older version we had that but in newer version react router doesn't provide this. So what can I use in newer version to work with browserHistory?

Comment: Use `react-router-dom` which is the latest.

Comment: Please check the snippet first. I'm already with `react-router-dom`

Comment: I did figure out the problem. it was with rendering the component from `Route`. I was using `Component` in my code but it should be `component` that's why my code wasn't working. It didn't event throw an error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newest version, you must use `BrowserRouter` to replace `browserHistory` option:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
  <div> ... </div>
  <Route />
  <Route />
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can read more about this in https://reacttraining.com/web/api/BrowserRouter